# Removing page numbering from the side of the page in Microsoft Word

Tags: microsoft-word

I'm having troubles removing the page numbers from the side of the page.

[image]

I cannot access this side even by double clicking, and "remove page numbers" don't appear in the "page numbers" drop down menu.

Comment: Which version of word? Is it a true word-file or open-office?

Answer (score 2):

For 2007+:

You can use the Remove Page Numbers command from the menu and it will remove some page numbers. To be fair, usually, it will remove all of them, but not always. If a page number was inserted directly as a field rather than through the menu, the remove command will not find it. If you restart numbering, the command will find only numbers in the current document section. The best method for removing page numbers that the command does not reach is to (1) move to any page still showing a page number and run the command again, and then (2) if you still have page numbers, go into the header editing layer and find those numbers and delete them. If they are in shapes, delete the shapes as well.

See also [here](http://www.addbalance.com/word/pagenumberremove.htm) for more details about older version.

In all cases use the inverted P to show code on the page. This helps finding your "page-number" code and you can remove it that way.
[image].

Answer (score 1):

ok, turns out it was a drawing object that was added to the header. If I double click the header I can remove it...